# What is it meant by local vs global objects in this article about dependency injection?

Tags: dependency-injection, global, local

What do the words `local` and `global` mean in [this article](https://blog.softwaremill.com/what-is-dependency-injection-8c9e7805502f) about dependency injection ?

Please see the quote below :

> Data objects, on the other hand, are created dynamically, either in
>   response to user interaction, API invocation, scheduled tasks, etc.
>   They usually have a short, **local** lifespan. They carry and
>   manipulate the data that the application processes. They might combine
>   data and behavior, or be pure, “thin”, data structures.
>
> The crucial property of the service/module graph is that it is created
>   statically. Only when the graph of services is wired, the application
>   is usually ready to serve user requests. Hence the service
>   objects/modules are static and **global**, as well as typically
>   stateless.

Answer (score 2):

The author is differentiating the service objects that compose an application vs the data objects used in an application. Services are global since they are commonly accessible (via injection) to the entire application. An object graph of such services are created when bootstrapping your application with DI. After this object graph is created, your application will use these same services throughout the application for the entire life of your application.

Data objects, on the other hand, have a local scope. They are created dynamically as needed, used, and then disposed.

For instance, supposed you have a UserRepositoryService and you want to register a new User. The UserRepsitoryService is configured and injected throughout your application (and thus global), but the User object is created dynamically in response to the request to create a new User. After the operation is complete, the User object can fall out of scope and be disposed.

```
public class Application {
    private IRepository<User> _userRepo = null;

    // UserRepositoryService injected through DI here
    public Application(IRespository<User> userRepo) { _userRepo = userRepo; }

    ...
    public void CreateUser(String userId) {
        User newUser = new User(userId);  // Data Object Created
        _userRepo.Insert(newUser);                   
    } //  Data Object falls out of scope here
}
```

This is a simple example, but hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for the answer still trying to wrap my head around DI so maybe first I need to understand some even more basic concepts before I try to understand the answer to this question. ( I came to the conclusion that this is on the "next level". I am missing the basics. )

Comment: @jhegedus The best remedy for that is to go through some example DI applications and get some experience writing your own. I think it takes everyone a while to grasp ioc, since it flips everything on its head.